# Using array of images as texture in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

How to use an array of textures (which contain different images) in WebGL without initializing each texture separately? I want to display a cube and a pyramid (organized as an array), each with a different texture image. Here is a part of the code (to initialize the textures):

```
function handleTexture(texture) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.Img);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function initTextures() {
    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        tex[i] = gl.createTexture();
        tex[i].Img = new Image();
        tex[i].Img.onload = function() { handleTexture(tex[i]); }
        tex[i].Img.src = texImgs[i];   // The name of the image file
    }
}
```

The cube and pyramid are displayed in black color (no texture), and I get this error in the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Img' of undefined  // gl.texImage2D()
tex.(anonymous function).Img.onload                          // tex[i].Img.onload = ...
```

I don't have this error if I initialize the texture separately, not using an array, but tex1 and tex2. Any suggestion on how to do this using array?

Comment: You can check [this](http://www.studyjs.com/webgl/texture.html) for adding texture to canvas in WebGL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
tex[i] = gl.createTexture();
```

`tex[i]` becomes a type of `WebGLTexture` and you cannot attach new properties on that object as you did with `.Img` property. So slightly more correct version would be:

```
var tex = [], texImgs = ['pyra.jpg', 'cube.jpg'];

function handleTexture(myTexture) {
    myTexture.texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, myTexture.texture);

    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, myTexture.image);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}

function initTextures() {
    for (var i=0; i<2; i++) {
        (function(index) {
            tex[index] = new Object();
            tex[index].texture = null;
            tex[index].image = new Image();
            tex[index].image.onload = function() { handleTexture(tex[index]); }
            tex[index].image.src = texImgs[index];   // The name of the image file
        })(i);
    }
}
```

Note that you create an object that has `image` and `texture` property separated.

Hope this helps you.

EDIT:

Closure messes the index of the `tex`.

Comment: Tried this, but now the cube and pyramid are not displayed. Then have this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Img' of undefined (in tex[i].Img = new Image()). Anyway, if I initialize the texture not using an array, but tex1 = gl.createTexture(), afterwards I still can set tex1.Img = new Image().

Comment: Edited answer, try creating `tex[i]` as new object, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: The cube and pyramid are displayed now, but still in black. Then there's this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'texture' of undefined (myTexture.texture = gl.createTexture())`.

Comment: Edited. I totally forgot about closure that doesn't exist in for loop, and async call of the `tex[i]`. It literally was trying to call `handleTexture` on `tex[3]`. This now should work 100%. :]

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. Anyway, it seems that WebGL really hates array.

Comment: JS hates undefined. ^^
Please accept and upvote my answer. Thanks.